# Dynamic form from view to controller

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an object that is the main object that is a required input to a form (which submits to a view model) and then I have a set of objects that are values that apply to that object. EX. Swiss army knife(main) with a set of values for all of its tools(values).

I want to dynamically add/remove (values) from the form and submit them all to the controller in one fell swoop. I have a view model with

```
public class GaugeViewModel
{
   public virtual Gauge Gauge { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Gauge> Gauges { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GaugeValues> GaugeValues { get; set; }
    public virtual GaugeValues GaugeValue { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best method for getting the form to dynamically create a list so that I can extract the values in the controller and submit them to my DB.

I would prefer to not have a third party library or anything added.

Comment: What have you tried? What I have done in the past for things like this is to have either a bunch of text boxes with the same name attribute and then have JS either remove / add textboxes. When you submit the MVC engine will serialize all of those inputs with the same to your viewmodel as long as your viewmodel property is an `IEnumerable`

Comment: so what you are saying is if I have the values be asp-for the same values for a IEnumerable it should automatically make them a list? (this sounds noob-ish because I am)